# IDE recommends to decorate Django CBV methods with @staticmethod

Tags: python, django, static-methods, django-class-based-views

The recommendation seems to make sense because `self` isn't used in the method, but now I'm curious:

- is it an oversight of CBV's and users should manually decorate each `@staticmethod`?
- is there already some code in Django that automagically makes all CBV methods static?

Here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about. It's using DRF's CBV, but it was the same recommendation when I was using vanilla Django CBV.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't do this. These are instance methods and need to remain so.

It does seem a bit odd though that you're not using any of the instance values or calling any instance methods there. Usually you would reference the URL arguments via `self.kwargs`, and call other methods such as `self.get_context_data`. If you're not doing any of that, I wonder if you're really getting any benefit from using CBVs at all.

(In fact my usual recommendation is that you don't override `get` or `post` at all; those usually delegate to more specific methods that are more useful to override.)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what a properly implemented cbv is supposed to look like, and tbh I don't even see any advantage to using cbv's. Should I just use function views until I find a reason to use cbv?